# Check if a part of a repo has not changed on a Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson

On a Jenkins build I'd like to skip some tests if a part of the repository hasn't changed. This could save a lot of time on the build process. Here's how I can do it on my dev machine:

```sh
changes=$(git log --name-only --pretty="" my_branch..HEAD | grep path/to/folder)
if [[ -z $changes ]]; then
  echo "no changes detected, skipping tests"
  exit 0
fi
echo "running tests!"
```

How do I do this on a Jenkins machine?

I'm using a [`git` plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and it can figure my branch name with `$GIT_BRANCH`, but I'm clueless how to get a list of file changes on my build.

Comment: Are you using pipeline or freestyle job in Jenkins?

Comment: @RobHales it's a freestyle job.

Comment: I just realized another option that is probably better than your shell script. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a Freestyle job, you will probably have to use the conditional build step plugin. I don't think you can run a shell script as one of the conditions, but you can run one step to execute your shell script you pasted, and have it touch a file if you should (or should not) run a test. Then use the Conditional Build Step to look for that file and do the right thing.

I also just realized that one of the Additional Behaviors that the git plugin has is *Polling ignores commits in certain paths*. This allows you to specify includes or excludes. If you specify the "Includes" the job won't even trigger a build at all if files other than those are modified. Then you don't even need your shell script or to take up an executor to check the changes.

Comment: Looks like Conditional BuildStep Plugin is exactly what I need. Skipping the whole build if the code paths haven't changed is a great advice too.